# Te-form and かつ and も？

Tags: て-form, adjectives, i-adjectives, particle-も, conjunctions

I'm reading a light novel and am stuck on a sentence. One big problem is this phrase:

> 優｛やさ｝しくて、かつ人間｛にんげん｝も

I know that ーくて is used to connect things, and my understanding of かつ is that it's a strong connector, but I don't understand it exactly.

The full, long sentence is:

> 吉田｛よしだ｝さんのような優｛やさ｝しくて、かつ人間｛にんげん｝も出来｛でき｝ている男性｛だんせい｝に恋人｛こいびと｝ができるのはごく普通｛ふつう｝のことだし、恋人｛こいびと｝になればそういうことがあるのも普通｛ふつう｝だ。

I was hoping someone could help me understand what parts of this sentence mean so I may continue reading my book lol, specifically:

What is the first phrase of the sentence supposed to mean? Does the ような only connect to 優｛やさ｝しくて? I would think the phrase would mean "kindness like Yoshida-san's" but the くて makes it seem like that's not how to translate it.

What exactly does かつ connect in this sentence? Does it connect everything before it and everything after it until the のは？

And finally, if someone could explain what this triple connector combination of て、かつ、And　も means in 優｛やさ｝しくて、かつ人間｛にんげん｝も then that'd help me a lot.

Thank you~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「人間ができている」 means "(someone) is a mature person".

So you should parse it like:

> [吉田さんのような][優しくて、かつ人間も出来ている]男性
>   A man [who is kind and at the same time mature], [like Yoshida-san]

「吉田さんのような」 connects to 「（優しくて、かつ人間もできている）男性」.

優しくて、かつ人間もできている modifies the noun 男性. 優しくて is the て form, ie the continuous form of 優しい, "is kind, and...". かつ means "besides" "furthermore" or "at the same time". も here is "too" "also", as in "He's kind. And he's mature, *too*."

Comment: ohhhhhhh I get it now, thanks!